# ASP.NET 5 site fails to publish to azure appservice because of a long path

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to publish a relatively new ASP.NET site to azure appservice from Visual Studio.

I'm getting the following error message during the preview:

> The "Dnu" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Exception: 
>   Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
>   Copying to output path C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp*****************.********.WebApi114
>
> Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>      at Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.Dnu.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Path is long indeed. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is from windows file API, not control by Azure App Service. Sadly I think you will have to find a way to shorter your file path in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Is there setting somewhere to set the output path of the publishing?

Comment: Try define "DEPLOYMENT_TEMP" in app setting to see if it work for you. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-Environment

Comment: in appsettings.json?

Comment: appsetting i mean settings that config thru portal.azre.com or via API. not appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue trying to build an Angular2 app locally. So I tend to agree with Xiaomin that it may be a local issue.  What worked for me was to run the dnu publish command from a command prompt with the output flag set with a shorter folder destination provided.  For example, navigate to the location of the project you want to publish in a command prompt and type:

"dnu publish --runtime active -o c:\Sample"

The above command will post your output to c:\Sample.

You can interrogate the options as follows:

"dnu -help"

"dnu publish -help"